# Scrolling a scrollbar with the TK GUI

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

How can a `TkScrollbar` be scrolled with code?

Neither `.scroll` nor `.autoscroll` are recognised.

```
 test = TkScrollbar.new(root).pack('side'=>'right', 'fill'=>'y')
 test.scroll(1)
 test.autoscroll
```

Edit: Forgot the link to the doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tk/rdoc/classes/Tk/Scrollbar.html

Comment: Which versions of Ruby (and TK) are you using? The linked doc is for Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Installed with 1.9.2 rubyinstaller (tk is in the stdlib that comes with ruby, it should be up to date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with ruby and tk, but with other tk bindings (python and tcl, to be precise), when you want to scroll something programmatically you don't move the scrollbar, you directly scroll whatever it is you want scrolled. The scrollbar will update itself to reflect the changes.

You scroll an object by using its `xview` and `yview` methods. I assume (but don't know for a fact) those are exposed in the ruby bindings.